# Trouble sending an event to another class in C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm relatively new to OOD, C#, WPF, but trying to learn.  So I have a main XAML that has a few controls in it.  One control is a DataGrid (dtGrid).  The DataGrid has its own code behind and has some methods for its class.  I am trying to create an event for when the scroll is done horizontally.  I have this:

```
 private void dtGrid_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.HorizontalChange != 0)
        {
            // update some stuff to main XAML
        }
    }
```

I don't see how the dtGrid has any visibility of the main XAML.  Since the dtGrid (DataGrid control) has its own code behind it where I put this method, I have no reference to the other controls that are in the main XAML by their Name.  Is there a way to get around this?  Thanks.

Edit: Additional Code and some psuedo code for brevity
So my main class that has the main XAML:

```
<UserControl>
<GroupBox Header="Sample" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5, 0, 5, 0" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold">
            <View:SampleControl x:Name="SampleControl" Background="Transparent" />
        </GroupBox>
</UserControl>
```

I have code behind this XAML where I need to make the update to the other object when the scroll is changed.  However, the problem I have is I have another XAML for the SampleControl which is:

```
<some UserControl and the namespaces>
<DataGrid x:Name="dtGridReads"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"                                       
            VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode ="Standard" 
              EnableColumnVirtualization="False"
              EnableRowVirtualization="False"
            ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
            CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True"
             ItemsSource ="{Binding}" Block.TextAlignment="Center"
             CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" FrozenColumnCount="1"
               GridLinesVisibility="None" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="10" Background="White"
              ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="dtGridReads_ScrollChanged" >
```

and then I have code-behind behind this XAML as well.  So I'm not sure where everything goes and who can communicate to who.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event of the datagrid is public and should be used outside the datagrid, most likely in the Window or UserControl that's hosting it:

In window (or any class *other* than the DataGrid class)

```
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
dg.ScrollChanged += DoSomething;


private void DoSomething(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.HorizontalChange != 0)
    {
        // update some stuff to main XAML which should now be available
    }
}
```

**Update**

If you want to see how to subscribe to the event from XAML you can use:

```
<DataGrid ScrollChanged="DoSomething" />
```

Comment: If the DoSomething method is private, how does the other non-DataGrid class subscribe to that method?

Comment: The DoSomething method would be declared on the same object that "owns" the datagrid. e.g.  If your window has a datagrid, then the window adds the event subscription to the datagrid instance (in code or in XAML as in the answer) and DoSomething is a private method in the window. If you wanted to post a bit more of your code I could update the answer with something more specific.

Comment: I added more code explaining what I have and the problem at hand.  Thanks for your help!